# Use git in jenkins pipeline with docker agent

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-pipeline

When I try to run the pipeline below, it fails with this error:

> Cloning into '/go/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket'...
>
> fatal: unable to look up current user in the passwd file: no such user
>
> package github.com/gorilla/websocket: exit status 128

As far as I understand, the issue is, that jenkins starts the container with the userid from the jenkins user, to keep the file system permissions right (docker run -t -d -u 108:113 ....) but how can I use git then?

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {

...

    stage('Build Code') {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'xxx.de/go_build_container'
                args '-v=$WORKSPACE:/go/src/bitbucket.org/xxx/service_donation'
            }
        }
        environment {
            HOME = "."
        }
        steps {
            sh 'cd /go/src/bitbucket.org/xxx/service_donation && go get github.com/gorilla/websocket'

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lot of programs won't work when running with a user id not existing in /etc/passwd and git is one of those programs.

You must specify a correct `-u` argument to your docker container, that is, one that exists in your `xxx.de/go_build_container` image, root (or 0:0) being one of them.
So put something like: `args '-v=$WORKSPACE:/go/src/bitbucket.org/xxx/service_donation -u 0:0'` and it will work.

Then, you will face another problem: the files created in your volume will belong to the UID you are using in your container, you may need to add some `chown` if you want to reuse those files later in your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks it helps me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Another option I found is mounting /etc/passwd to the container.

```
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'xxxx'
                args '-v=/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd'
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure, if that has any other problems but it seems to work and you don't have the problem with wrong permissions.